# ES6 shorthand import

Tags: import, ecmascript-6

Is there a shorter ES6 way of doing:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
```

than

```
import chai from 'chai';
var assert = chai.assert;
```

(chai is the [chai-assertion](http://chaijs.com/) library, in case you haven't heard of it yet.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like:

```
import { assert } from 'chai';
```

`assert` must be exporting from `chai` in that case. See [spec here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-static-and-runtime-semantics-module-records) and [about es6 modules here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

Comment: How do you make it work? Node doesn't understand es6 by default :(

Comment: @antonavy use transpilers (for example babel with require hook https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/). BTW Node (v8 more precisely) supports a lot of es6 features already

Comment: If using mocha use "mocha --compilers <path to ts-node and register like node_modules/ts-node/register> name of filename.ts" after npm install ts-node

Comment: I know this is an old post but for anyone searching - as of node v13 or higher you can put { "type": "module" } in your package.json to use ES6 import instead of babel or the experimental flags.

Comment: Kind of pointless as chai doesn't export `assert` like that. This answer will NOT work for chai (at least not in version 8).

Answer (score 9):

You can use it like this:

```js
import * as chai from 'chai';

let assert = chai.assert;
let should = chai.should();
let expect = chai.expect;
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd rather:

```
import {assert, should, expect}  from 'chai';
```

Comment: It doesn't work for `should`: http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#using-should-in-es2015

With your solution you'll have to use `should().not.equal` instead of `should.not.equal`

Comment: yeap, you just do:
`should('value1').not.be.equal('value2)`

Comment: or 
`expect('someValue').to.be.ok`

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```js
import chai from 'chai';
const { assert } = chai;
```